# Freeing a character pointer returns error

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I'm trying to free a character pointer after having used it but it returns a strange error.

The error says:

> _CrtDbgREport: String too long or IO Error

The debugger itself returns no errors while compiling.

The code currently looks like this:

```
void RespondToUser(SOCKET client, SOCKET server)
{
    char buffer[80];
    char *temp = malloc(_scprintf("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n%s\r\nServer: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nHi!", buffer, SERVER_NAME));
    sprintf(temp, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n%s\r\nServer: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nHi!", buffer, SERVER_NAME);

    send(client, temp, strlen(temp), 0);
    closesocket(client);
    free(temp);
    ListenToUsers(server);
}
```

The problem only occurs when I try to free the temp pointer from the memory and not otherwise. What might be causing this?

Comment: In addition to what hmjd wrote, you're reading from uninitialized `buffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `sprintf()` is writing one past the end (as it appends a NULL terminator), as the return value from `_scprintf()` does not include the NULL terminator. From [`_scprintf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32cf9tb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) reference page:

> Returns the number of characters that would be generated if the string were to be printed or sent to a file or buffer using the specified formatting codes. **The value returned does not include the terminating null character.**

This means the program has undefined behaviour. To correct `+ 1` to `_scprintf()`s return value.